# HTML NEWSLETTER : Image with wrapped link isn't clickable on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, hyperlink, newsletter, clickable

I've wrote a HTML Newsletter and have a link (a href) around my image.
It's typical and valid HTML code.

But if I test my newsletter on iPhone and try to click on that image to follow my link.
iphone menu pops out and I can share the link, save the image .. etc.  but I cannot open the Link!

I don't know why?! AAaargh.

It's a HTML Newsletter, I can't use JavaScript.

```
<td width="253" valign="middle">
   <a href="http://mydomain.com/mydocument.pdf" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://mydomain.com/button.png" width="253" height="39" alt="My Image" style="display:block;" border="0" />
   </a>
  </td>
```

Comment: try removing the `target="_blank"` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is ...

Make a Imagemap over the graphics-element It' works

```
<img src="button.png" width="253" height="39" alt="" style="display:block;" border="0" usemap="linkmap" />
```

an then .

```
<map name="linkmap">
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,253,39" href="http://mydomain.com/mydocument.pdf" target="_blank" alt="" />
```